# Microphone input in HTML for Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am developing a web app with Flask and [speech recognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) for audio inputs, processing and displaying an output on screen. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63431906/8534756) has helped me organize the input of audio files, here is my flask code:

```
list_msg = []

@app.route("/process_wav", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process_wav():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        audio_file = request.form.get("audio-recording")
        dir = 'audio/'+str(audio_file)
        msg = Mensaje(dir)  # this is a custom class I created for storing and processing the audio
        list_msg.append((dir, msg.sentence, msg.word_counter))
    return render_template("process_wav.html", list_msg=list_msg)
```

and my HTML code:

```
{% block flask %}
<h1>Prototype</h1>

<section>
<form action="" method="POST" class="form-input">
<div class="form-input">
  <label for="audio-recording">Audio file (.wav)</label>
  <input name="audio-recording" type="file" accept="audio/*" id="audio-recording" >
  <button class="form-submit" type="submit" id="entry">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
</section>

{% for msg in list_msg %}
<section class="form-output" id="output">
  <h3>{{ msg[0] }}</h3>
  <p>Result: "{{ msg[1] }}"</p>
  <p>Counter: {{ msg[2] }}</p>
</section>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock flask %}
```

but I find it necessary to input audio **directly through a microphone** (and to process it the same way as with the .wav audio files). So my question is: how could I input audio through a microphone to the web page, in HTML, so that I pass it to Flask and python for processing and then displaying the output?

Being new to Flask and HTML, I find it hard to look for good references, although I found out that HTML does not offer this natively. Any advice is welcome

Comment: This answer may get you on the right track: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60850613/5252522.

You can utilize JS to send audio to Flask and this answer should assist in capturing that data.

Edit: The question provides the JS necessary for frontend audio capture: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60032983/5252522

Comment: @Quentin your comment helped me tons, I appreciate it. Now I'm using that code from the answer by Arunavo Ray, but it seems the `request.files['audio_data]` is not found because the request.files dictionary is empty, why could that be? PS: i haven't altered the app.js, and I tested it as-is and saw it worked as intended (returned the audio recording onto the browser)

Comment: Did you add the related JS frontend code?

Comment: @Quentin if you mean the JS script other than app.js then yes. It’s called recorder.js and it’s referenced in a web URL

Comment: Hmm... Maybe inspect the frontend to ensure the data is being sent

Answer (score -1):

function to stream audio live using flask. Actually i didn't get what you acutually want to do. But this way you can stream audio in flask.

```py
@app.route("/fetchAudio",methods=["GET"])
def fetch_audio():
    def generate():
       with open("SampleAudio.mp3", "rb") as audio: # your audio file path here
          audio_data = audio.read(1024)
       while audio_data:
            yield audio_data
            audio_data = audio.read(1024)
    return Response(generate(), mimetype="audio/x-wav") # header for audio type
```

I hope this'll help. [github_link](https://github.com/pritam-raj/music-simulation-flask-api)

Comment: basically I intend on having the website's visitor to say something to their computer microphone (audio input) which then gets passed to the Python backend so that I can transcribe it with the SpeechRecognition module, and finally return the transcribed text (alognside some other basic text computations) back to the display.